# Does a dual Nigerian-UK citizen need an ILR stamp to leave the UK?

Tags: uk-citizens, dual-nationality, nigerian-citizens

I have just heard  from a friend that if you have dual citizenship, you will have to have "NTL" stamped on your passport (not the British one) before you can travel out of Britain. I have two passports: one Nigerian, the other British. I do not have "indefinite leave to remain" stamped on my Nigerian passport because I was given indefinite leave to remain as a refugee more than 15 years ago; at that time, passports of refugees were not stamped.  What do I do now? Are there new rules about this?  Do i need to stamp my Nigerian passport?  This is very confusing for me.

Comment: could the "expatriates" site be more help to you?

Comment: Can you not just use your British passport? Also, if your Nigerian passport is more than 15 years old, is it even valid?

Comment: Your friend fed you a load of tosh

Comment: You no longer have indefinite leave to remain because you are a British citizen.  With British citizenship you acquired the right of abode, so you no longer require "leave to remain."

Comment: @JonathanReez No, this is not a duplicate. It is asking specific questions about stamps in the Nigerian passport of dual UK-Nigerian nationals; it is not a generic question about how to use two passports. I'm actually becoming _very_ concerned that somebody who's up for election as a moderator has such a scattergun approach to closing questions as duplicates. You seem to be proposing every single question that mentions having two passports as being a duplicate of the how to use two passports question. Please check that the questions are actually duplicates before voting to close.

Comment: @JonathanReez What's wrong with being a bit more careful _now_. I've just found 22 close votes in the review queue and I've a feeling I'm voting "leave open" on about half of them because they simply are not duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a passport check to get out of the country.

The airline will generally check your passport to make sure you have permission to enter the destination (they have to bear the cost of returning you if you are refused entry) and the staff at security and boarding will normally check some form of Id matches your ticket - but mostly to make sure you paid for a flight.

How would they know you also had a Nigerian passport ?

If you are flying to Nigeria and present your Nigerian passport to the checkin staff they might notice that you didn't have an entry stamp to the UK, assuming you entered on your UK passport, but they shouldn't care.